# Sorting Stored Procedure Results using Linq from another method

Tags: c#, linq, api, asmx

Is there some way where I could get the results that I want? All I see is that it just keeps on passing the values from another but the linq code is not working. I'm quite new to C# so I'm not used to it yet. Sorry.

```
    public List<BranchCinemaScheduleSelectStartEndTime> GetMoviesBranchCinemas(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime,int branchKey)
    {


       List<XScheduleFromDate> GetRecords = new List<XScheduleFromDate>();
       List<BranchCinemaScheduleSelectStartEndTime> branchSchedule = new List<BranchCinemaScheduleSelectStartEndTime>();

        // getting the results of my stored procedure
      GetRecords = XML_GetMoviesFromBranch(startTime, endTime, branchKey);

       // trying to linq but it's not working
       IEnumerable query = from bs in GetRecords.ToList()
                           where bs.Cinemas == "Cinema 1"
                           select bs;
```

Comment: what is not working? you are not getting filtered list? can you post your complete function

Comment: I just want to try if the linq code is working. I want to sort the result passed to the variable GetRecords. I'm expecting 3 counts while using breakpoint. But it just display the same count from the stored procedure. I don't know if I'm missing some code or do I have to do something with the GetRecords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to execute the query to get the result like below or
You can just filter the records using below code. It will return the records in which Cinemas == "Cinema 1"

```
  var filteredRecords = (from bs in GetRecords
                       where bs.Cinemas == "Cinema 1"
                       select bs).ToList();

                            OR 
  var filteredRecords = GetRecords.Where(r=>r.Cinemas == "Cinema 1").ToList();
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much! :)